# Go url.Parse(string) fails with certain user names or passwords

Tags: url, go, build

Using a URL that has worked in the past, I know receive a parsing error from `net/url`. What's wrong with it?

```
parse postgres://user:abc{DEf1=ghi@example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require: net/url: invalid userinfo
```

### Sample application

See https://play.golang.com/p/mQZaN5JN3_q to run.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "postgres://user:abc{DEf1=ghi@example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require"

    u, err := url.Parse(dsn)
    fmt.Println(u, err)
}
```

Comment: If you're seeing the std lib packages being built locally, that just means your local Go install isn't correct, you're cross compiling, or you're supplying the `-a` flag to `go install`.

Comment: @JimB Ok, thank you for clarifying this. I'm not supplying `-a`, just using the command as above. So this would be unrelated to the issue of ending up with different, I guess?

Comment: The output you see is unrelated, but if you say the local binary works correctly, then there must be a difference. Are your deps all vendored (if they are you wouldn't need to run `dep ensure`), or pulling the exact same version? Start by building your project with the exact same go version, in a clean GOPATH.

Comment: Only the `Gopkg.lock` is committed at this stage (the project still rapidly evolving), hence the `dep ensure` command.

Comment: @JimB After trying a build locally using the same Docker container I was able to reproduce the issue and can rule out AWS CodePipeline. The question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you have the same version of Go locally? I have a feeling that you just have an old (or modified?) version locally that's not catching the invalid character in the user info. If you escape the `{` it works correctly: https://play.golang.org/p/ifFpjYybNj4

Comment: I checked again, it got caused by a change in v1.9.4 that got released yesterday. My apologies . After updating locally to v1.9.4 the behaviour is identical no matter the platform.

Comment: @JimB I just updated the question with the full explanation, it may still be useful for others?

Comment: @klotz It's recommended you instead answer your own question with the solution, instead of editing it into the question. As it stands now, this question might be deleted, since it is no longer really a question.

Comment: @Unsigned thanks for pointing it out, rewrote the question and posted accurate answer.

Comment: @klotz No problem. Be sure to accept your answer too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out up until Go v1.9.3 `net/url` didn't validate the user info when parsing a url. This may break existing applications when compiled using v1.9.4 if the username or password contain special characters.

It now expects the user info to be percent encoded string in order to handle special characters. The new behaviour got introduced in [`ba1018b`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ba1018b4549f3edc257221cc8e49221255e03290).

### Fixed sample application

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    dsn1 := "postgres://user:abc{DEf1=ghi@example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require" // this works up until 1.9.3 but no longer in 1.9.4
    dsn2 := "postgres://user:abc%7BDEf1=ghi@example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require" // this works everywhere, note { is now %7B

    u, err := url.Parse(dsn1)
    fmt.Println("1st url:\t", u, err)

    u, err = url.Parse(dsn2)
    fmt.Println("2nd url:\t", u, err)
}
```

Run the code on https://play.golang.com/p/jGIQgbiKZwz.

Comment: with postgres://user:abc{DEf1=ghi@example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require have chance to set this url in conf (including password). It's more secure to separate password..

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can just

```
url.QueryEscape("your#$%^&*(proper$#$%%^(password")
```

and use this one to parse your url.

Answer (score 3):

Use url.UserPassword func :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "postgres://example.com:5432/db?sslmode=require" 

    u, err := url.Parse(dsn)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
         return
    }
    u.User = url.UserPassword("user", "abc{DEf1=ghi")
    fmt.Println("url:\t", u)

}
```